# Squid Enable SSL not working

Tags: squid, openssl, transparent-proxy

So I've compiled Squid myself with the following options:

```
Squid Cache: Version 3.3.8
configure options:  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/squid3' '--srcdir=.' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--disable-silent-rules' '--datadir=/usr/share/squid3' '--sysconfdir=/etc/squid3' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--enable-inline' '--enable-async-io=8' '--enable-storeio=ufs,aufs,diskd,rock' '--enable-removal-policies=lru,heap' '--enable-delay-pools' '--enable-cache-digests' '--enable-underscores' '--enable-icap-client' '--enable-follow-x-forwarded-for' '--enable-auth-basic=DB,fake,getpwnam,LDAP,MSNT,MSNT-multi-domain,NCSA,NIS,PAM,POP3,RADIUS,SASL,SMB' '--enable-auth-digest=file,LDAP' '--enable-auth-negotiate=kerberos,wrapper' '--enable-auth-ntlm=fake,smb_lm' '--enable-external-acl-helpers=file_userip,kerberos_ldap_group,LDAP_group,session,SQL_session,unix_group,wbinfo_group' '--enable-url-rewrite-helpers=fake' '--enable-eui' '--enable-esi' '--enable-icmp' '--enable-ssl' '--with-open-ssl' '--enable-ssl-crtd' '--enable-zph-qos' '--enable-ecap' '--disable-translation' '--with-swapdir=/var/spool/squid3' '--with-logdir=/var/log/squid3' '--with-pidfile=/var/run/squid3.pid' '--with-filedescriptors=65536' '--with-large-files' '--with-default-user=proxy' '--enable-linux-netfilter' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
```

Using the command squid3 -v I can see that '--enable-ssl' is in there.

However using squid3 -k parse I see this:

```
Processing: https_port 0.0.0.0:3130 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=16MB cert=/etc/squid3/ssl_certs/myCA.pem
ERROR: 'https_port' requires --enable-ssl
```

So... I'm confused. Is this a bug or something?

**Edit**

I have these lines in my config:

```
http_port 3129
http_port 0.0.0.0:3128 intercept
https_port 0.0.0.0:3130 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=16MB cert=/etc/squid3/ssl_certs/myCA.pem
```

Comment: To me it looks like you are missing `--enable-ssl` option in Squid runtime configuration.

Comment: What do you mean?

Added relevant config lines to the main post.

Comment: Actually Squid's error message is a bit misleading, it doesn't say explicitly if it is a missing compile or runtime option. Forget the above comment...

Comment: Ah damn, I was hoping that you'd realised some stupid mistake I'd made lol. 

From what I can see in this thread:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/squid/+bug/16669

SSL isn't supported by Squid 3.3.8 which is weird.

Answer (score -1):

Change `--with-open-ssl` to `--with-openssl` in your compile options.